# Progressive fill color and hide image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, colors, fill

I would be thankfull for some help in this matter please.

I have some divs that form squares of 200x200px with a thick solid border of white and an image inside. I would want that when I click ok a menu icon ("refs") it appears that way, and when I click on another ("skills") it will hide the image and animate a progressive fill color from bottom to top with white and form a specific word in the middle of the square .
Can you please help me with this :)

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the .animate() or .fadeIn() in jquery for this.
http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

More explained : You give a common class name to all the squares and then call out a click function for the class.

```
 $('.imagesquares').click(function(){
     Function for fadeIn and close goes here
 });
```

Check out fadeIn() examples provided and you can proceed well i think.

Cheers

Comment: Sorry i'm a little bit new at this. This is my first project with js. Do you think you can help me on it Roy?